# How to debug and inspect a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, debugging, recursion

I was wondering if someone could explain to me the following solution:

```
function smallestInt(arr) {
 if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
 return (Math.min(arr[0],smallestInt(arr.slice(1))));
}
console.log(smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60, 12, 33, 21]));  // 8
```

In particular, what the stack would look like. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the stack yourself with a debugger? The call stack would look something like `smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60, ..., 21]) -> smallestInt([12, 8, 60, ..., 21]) -> smallestInt([8, 60, ..., 21]) -> ... -> smallestInt([21])`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `console.log` is great for quick debugging. It's easy to reach for and is a great tool to have in your box but it is not the only one. There's much to be gained in learning how to use a debugger too.

### Setting up the debugging session

1. Open the Dev Tools and select the `Sources` tab
2. Create a new snippet and add your code
3. In the left margin click on L2. The blue arrow is a breakpoint.
4. Run your code

[image]

### Running the debugging session

The debugger will now stop every single time L2 is reached. See the screencast below. Note how the debugger displays the current state of `arr` in the top right corner:

[image]

Another thing you can do is "go back in time". Note how we can inspect each step in the stack back and forth. (See bottom right.)

[image]

---

Unless it is an exercise you don't need recursion for this. Here are a couple of alternatives:

```js
Math.min(...[42, 12, 8, 60, 12, 33, 21]);
//=> 8
```

Or with reduce:

```js
[42, 12, 8, 60, 12, 33, 21].reduce((n, x) => Math.min(n, x), Infinity)
//=> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simply comparing the last and the second last index and selecting the smaller in each step.

```js
// You can print it with slight rearrangement of the code 
   
function smallestInt(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];

    let last = smallestInt(arr.slice(1))
    let res = (Math.min(arr[0], last));

    console.log(arr[0], last, res);

    return res;
}
console.log(smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60, 12, 33, 21]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets take small array
[42, 12, 8, 60]

So Its start with finding min value between 42 and result returned by resursive call to `smallestInt([12, 8, 60])`. Here we call `smallestInt` by removing 1st index element from our array.
If we were to expand this call stack out, it would look like this:

```
smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60]) = Math.min(42, smallestInt([12, 8, 60]));
```

Now our previous `smallestInt` call will have more than 1 length array so it does make further recursive call to self by setting 1st element as a first parameter to `Math.min` and second parameter as calling `smallestInt` with array removing 1st index element. i.e. 12. So our call stack will looks like this.

```
smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60]) = Math.min(42, Math.min(12, smallestInt([8, 60]));
```

And again same as previous:

```
smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60]) = Math.min(42, Math.min(12, Math.min(8, smallestInt([60]))));
```

Since now our `smallestInt([60])` gets 1 length array `[60]` as input; `if (arr.length === 1)` condition gets satisfied. i.e `smallestInt` will return 60. And we break out of recursive call.

Now It starts traversing reverse. ie. It will start finding min value.

```
smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60]) = Math.min(42, Math.min(12, Math.min(8, 60)));
smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60]) = Math.min(42, Math.min(12, 8));
smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60]) = Math.min(42, 8);
smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 60]) = 8;
```

And finally returns 8;

Answer (score 0):

The following steps can be log output as

```js
let stage = 0;

function smallestInt(arr) {
  console.log(`arr = [${arr}]`);
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];

  let temp, newArr;
  const min = Math.min(arr[0], temp = smallestInt(newArr = arr.slice(1)));
  console.log(`stage: ${stage++} => Math.min(arr[0] = ${arr[0]}, smallestInt( arr.slice(1)) = [${newArr}] = ${min}`)

  return min;
}
console.log(smallestInt([42, 12, 8, 16]));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Let's go process step by step

**1)** When the function starts

```
arr = [42,12,8,16]
```

*NOTE: and we know that `arr.length is not equal to 1` so it won't return `arr[0]`*

and we are returning the result value of

```
Math.min(arr[0],smallestInt(arr.slice(1)))
```

which can be interpreted as:

```
Math.min(arr[0] = 42, smallestInt( arr.slice(1)) = [12,8,16] // recursion here
```

---

**2)** When the function starts

```
arr = [12,8,16]
```

*NOTE: and we know that `arr.length is not equal to 1` so it won't return `arr[0]`*

and we are returning the result value of

```
Math.min(arr[0],smallestInt(arr.slice(1)))
```

which can be interpreted as:

```
Math.min(arr[0] = 12, smallestInt( arr.slice(1)) = [8,16] // recursion here
```

---

**3)** When the function starts

```
arr = [8,16]
```

*NOTE: and we know that `arr.length is not equal to 1` so it won't return `arr[0]`*

and we are returning the result value of

```
Math.min(arr[0],smallestInt(arr.slice(1)))
```

which can be interpreted as:

```
Math.min(arr[0] = 8, smallestInt( arr.slice(1)) = [16] // recursion here
```

---

**4)** When the function starts

```
arr = [16]
```

**NOTE: The `arr.length is equal to 1` so it will return `arr[0]` that is 16**

---

**3)** Now the value returned from `smallestInt( newArr = arr.slice( 1 ) )` is `16` so the returned value of function will be

```
Math.min(8, 16)  ===> 8 will be out returned value of whole function
```

---

**2)** Now the value returned from `smallestInt( newArr = arr.slice( 1 ) )` is `8` so the returned value of function will be

```
Math.min(12, 8)  ===> 8 will be out returned value of whole function
```

---

**1)** Now the value returned from `smallestInt( newArr = arr.slice( 1 ) )` is `8` so the returned value of function will be

```
Math.min(42, 8)  ===> 8 will be out returned value of whole function
```

**So the final value of `console.log( smallestInt( [42, 12, 8, 16] ) );` will be `8`**